# jquery not populating dropdown options in ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Good day,

I am populating a dropdown using ajax. The data is coming from my mvc controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetResult()
    {
        var result = _IInterface.GetList();
        //result is a list that have name, lastname and Id
        if (result == null) return null;
        var jsons= Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return jsons;
    }
```

In my front end my ajax call is getting the data from my action result without any problem.
This is my part of my view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePaper", new AjaxOptions()
{
OnSuccess= "ajaxSuccess"
}))
{
 <select id=" countryDropDownList">
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
    </select>
```

The ajax call

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Author/GetAuthors",

            success: function (data) {

                var options = '';
                var mySelect = $('#countryDropDownList');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + data[i].Name + " " + data[i].LastName + '">' + "test" + '</option>'; 

                }
                console.log(options);   
                $("#countryDropDownList").appendTo(options);
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("sdfgsdgsdfd");                  
            }
        });          
});
```

When I inspect the console.log(options) I get this:

```
<option value="asdfasd sagasdg">test</option><option value="Select">Select</option>
```

my problem is that my code is not appending the options. What is wrong?thanks

I already looked for in different places:


[AJAX Call For Dropdown Lists In MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-call-for-dropdown-lists-in-mvc/)

[Append items to dropdown jQuery / Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435934/append-items-to-dropdown-jquery-ajax)

[How do I add options to a DropDownList using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

Comment: I am not getting any error in the console

Comment: Probably not your main issue, but you should return `[]` rather than `null` if there are none found. Otherwise, you will say `var i = 0; i < data.length;...` which will evaluate to `null.length` which will throw a type error

Comment: Does your select tag look like this? `<select id="countryDropDownList">`.

Comment: difference is `appendTo` vs `append`

Comment: it looks like the one you said <select id=" countryDropDownList">
            <option value="Select">Select</option>
        </select>

Comment: Yes, that could be the problem.  If your select is `<select id="countryDropDownList">` then use `append` instead of `appendTo`.  Also, remove the leading space in your id attribute.

Comment: the error was caused by a small space leadiny in my id..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have a leading space in your `id` attribute of your `<select>` list. This may have been a typo when you copied your code over, but if it is that way in your code - that will be problematic, as `$("#myId")` will not pick up `<elem id=" myId"></elem>`

Secondly, you should be using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) not [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) - there is a great explanation of the difference between the two [in this article](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/50031633dd2be800020302b5)

You should also return `[]` rather than `null` from your MVC controller if there are none found. Otherwise, you will say `var i = 0; i < data.length;...` which will evaluate to `null.length` which will throw a type error